# what does #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 mean

Tags: mysql

I am brand new to MySQL and to all database langues as a whole so excuse me if this is just a dumb error. i am writing my first database and started by making the coulombs of CrayFish, Hooks, LiveBait, Spinners, and Worms. in it i put this command.

```
INSERT INTO gear (CrayFish, Hooks, LiveBait, Spinners, Worms) values ('big', 'small'), ('size5', 'size4', 'size3', 'size2', 'size1'), ('nightCrawlers', 'frog', 'liveMinos', 'bloodWorms'),('perch', 'mino', 'sunfish'), ('pink', 'orange', 'green');
```

I am getting the error: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. I have looked online but none of the answers I saw fix my problem. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says.  Here are your columns:

```
(CrayFish, Hooks, LiveBait, Spinners, Worms)
```

And here are your values:

```
('big', 'small')
```

5 is not equal to 2.  The counts need to match.  If you want to leave the rest null, explicitly define that:

```
('big', 'small', NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

I suspect the rest of that query is wrong, too.  You're probably going to have an error on that next comma.

Upon further inspection, it looks like you're trying to insert all of the rows for a given column one column at a time?  Tables don't work like that.  Though from the values and the column names it's difficult to discern specifically what you're trying to do.

Either way, an `INSERT` statement inserts a single row of values at one time.  Define that row of values, insert it, repeat for other rows.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax an insert statement is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name_1, column_name_2, ..., column_name_n)VALUES (value_1,value_2,...,value_n);
```

when you insert a row into a table you need to specify the value that will be inserted into each column for the row. You can also only insert one row at a time.

You need to try something like

```
INSERT INTO gear (CrayFish, Hooks, LiveBait, Spinners, Worms) values ('big', 'size5','nightCrawlers', 'perch','pink');
```

to insert one row into the gear table